# Github and Heroku repos? How to read, push, pull, and generally keep them synced

Tags: git, github, repository, heroku

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [git push to multiple repositories simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255865/git-push-to-multiple-repositories-simultaneously)

I want to let other people read my rails app from github.

So I usually push repos to github and heroku. Now I want to do both with one app and keep them synced. How do you do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can start by pushing to [multiple repos at one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165092/can-i-push-to-more-than-one-repository-in-a-single-command-in-git) (configured [with `git remote`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations), like [`git remote set-url`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620525/git-pushing-to-two-repos-in-one-command)).

```
git remote add all github:path/proj.git
git remote set-url --add --push all url = heroku:path/proj.git
```

That would generate a config like:

```
[remote "all"]
  url = github:path/proj.git
  url = heroku:path/proj.git
```

then:

```
git push all --all.
```

If your repos are writable only for you, you don't need to fetch from all of them in one operation. You only need to keep them update in one push.