# Mirroring a repository across Github, Sourceforge and Google Code

Tags: git, github, google-code, sourceforge

Is it possible to mirror a git repository (sync across all hosts) on GitHub, SourceForge and Google Code given they all support git?

Comment: I assume you want them to stay in sync more or less automagically?  Would you be committing to all of them, or just one (or none of them)?

Comment: @R0MANARMY Yes I'm going to commit only one repo thats it, that commit should sync with all other repo hosted on different servers like I mentioned.

Answer (score 11):

You can edit your `.git/config` file to create a remote that pushes to multiple repositories.

```
[remote "everyone"]
    url = https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
    url = ssh://USERNAME@git.code.sf.net/p/PROJECTNAME/MOUNTPOINT
    url = https://PROJECT.googlecode.com/git
```

or with the `git config --add` command:

```
git config --add remote.everyone.url https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
git config --add remote.everyone.url ssh://USERNAME@git.code.sf.net/p/PROJECTNAME/MOUNTPOINT
git config --add remote.everyone.url https://PROJECT.googlecode.com/git
```

Now when you type `git push everyone master`, you'll push the master branch to all three remotes.

Thanks to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/166043/19818) for the clue.