# git repository is not reflecting the changes made even after git push

Tags: git, repository, push

I have a git repository on a server (say gitserver) . I have cloned it to another server on the same farm (mysql server) .  on the mysql server , I do a

```
    touch version.txt
```

add a few lines to it.

```
    git add version.txt
    git commit -am "added version text" .
    git push origin master
```

output :

```
    git push origin master
    Counting objects: 5, done.
    Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 309 bytes, done.
    Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
    remote: warning: updating the current branch
    To root@ec2-54-197-239-43.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/opt/liveupdate/sqldb
    cb8ba55..ee4dab5  master -> master
```

On the liveupdate server , when I tried to see the file (`version.txt`) that I had added , I am unable to do so.

```
    git status
```

gives me the following output .

```
    # On branch master
    # Changes to be committed:
    #   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
    #
    #       modified:   version.txt
    #
    # Changed but not updated:
    #   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
    #   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    #
    #       deleted:    version.txt
    #
```

And then on the gitserver I do a commit with the following output:

```
     git commit
     [master 4d8975a] adding version.txt
     1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

after all this , when I do a `ls -a`, shouldn't I be able to see that `version.txt` on gitserver  ?

Comment: If you only push to a server, no changes are made on the filesystem. In fact, only the index gets updated. Could you post the relevant part of a `git log --graph --pretty=format:'%h -%d %s'` on both servers? I think you just reverted your commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a push to a non bare repo, on the checked out branch.

Ideally, you should have gotten an [error - `refusing to update checked out branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2816369/1860929), but you seem to have already ignored the  options using [`receive.denyCurrentBranch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8985873/1860929) in your liveupdate server, and hence the files are appearing in the current state.

To avoid this, in your liveupdate server repo, do a `git reset HEAD && git checkout .` (and not a commit as you have already done - Check how to [undo it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/927358/1860929))

Ideally, you should use an [intermediate bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19133278/1860929), so that you can push to the bare repo and pull from it later.

Comment: Hi , Yea i was able to resolve this .Thanks so much !